# neo4j browser not showing relationships

Tags: neo4j

I have a strange issue .

I have a simple query in neo4j which iv'e used in the past, which shows me a path from source labels to target labels .

This is the query :

```
match (d:Dashboard)<-[r*]-(t:Table) where t.Name = 'TBL_RAWDATA_POPAI_KBL'  return t,r,d
```

Now , the thing is , that when running this query on the browser , it just shows me the source table node, and the target dashboard nodes, without displaying the relationships. it just shows a bunch of disconnected nodes.

But , if i switch over to the 'rows' output in the browser , i see the relationships, it is just that they are not being displayed .

I thought it might have anything to do with the visualization limits ( although the number of nodes and edges is that needs to be returned in this query is not that high) - so changed in the settings tab to high values - still didn't help.

This query used to visualize well in the past ( before i updated the nodes) . still , i know that this issue is not due to the amount of nodes ( fairly small) .

Any ideas what else can cause the browser not to visualize this  ?

*Edit :

I'll also mention that when i changed the query to

```
match (d)<-[r*]-(t:Table) where t.Name = 'TBL_RAWDATA_POPAI_KBL'  return t,r,d
```

(meaning , i removed the label from (d) ) , the browser visualized everything it was supposed to (which included the target nodes who has the 'Dashboard' Label), but i want it to work like it did in the past, with a label on (d)

*Edit 2 :

Another thing worth mentioning is that what i use this query :

```
match Path=(d:Dashboard)<-[r*]-(t:Table { Name : 'TBL_RAWDATA_POPAI_KBL' }) return Path
```

meaning, keeping the labels but returning a path rather than 'd,r,t' , i do get the visualization of the edges and nodes in between the source and targets.

Comment: In the Graph view, did you set the auto-complete feature to ON (in the lower right corner)?

Comment: It was on , changed it to off ( in the settings tab as well ) so that in new visualization it will be set to off as well. Still same behaviour -> not showing the relations, just the source nodes and target nodes, disconnected

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that what i use this query :                    "match Path=(d:Dashboard)<-[r*]-(t:Table { Name : 'TBL_RAWDATA_POPAI_KBL' })   return Path"   meaning, keeping the labels but returning a path rather than  'd,r,t' , i do get the visualization of the edges and nodes in between the source and targets.

Comment: @AvichayMarciano Give a minimal example of the data for which this behavior can be obtained. For example on http://console.neo4j.org

Comment: Any idea how i can take the output of my underlying data to the online console ? tried to export using to cypher script file using APOC   procedures , but neo4j client fails on constructing from the commands there.  basically, my edges have properties as well, and they are from varying types. does it matter \ has anything to do with the browser refusing to display them ?  isn't it strange that they are displayed only when in a path context or when the destination nodes are not filtered by a label?